# How to order descending JSON content

Tags: json.net

I'm trying ordering JSON data based on column called "Priority".

Follow JSON Content Partial:

```
{
"Threads": 
{
    "Program1" : 
    {
        "Filepath": "C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)...",
        "Priority": 0
    },
    "Program2" : 
    {
        "Filepath": "C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)...",
        "Priority": 1
    }
}}
```

Expected:

```
    {
    "Threads": 
    {
        "Program2" : 
        {
            "Filepath": "C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)...",
            "Priority": 1
        },
        "Program1" : 
        {
            "Filepath": "C:\\ProgramFiles(x86)...",
            "Priority": 0
        }
    }}
```

Tried the code below but throw error:

```
JObject jsonFile = JObject.Parse(JSONContent);                                  
var sortedObject = new JObject(jsonFile["Threads"].OrderByDescending(obj => (int) obj["Priority"] ) ); #<= Throw error.
```

Any idea to solve this solution?

Comment: parse it into a model, and then sort it

Comment: *Deserialize* into a model/DTO and then sort it

Comment: I find the JSON structure strange - I'd expect "Threads" to be an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working using `JObject` but it's not pretty:

```
var json = "{\r\n\"Threads\": \r\n{\r\n    \"Program1\" : \r\n    {\r\n        \"Filepath\": \"C:\\\\ProgramFiles(x86)...\",\r\n        \"Priority\": 0\r\n    },\r\n    \"Program2\" : \r\n    {\r\n        \"Filepath\": \"C:\\\\ProgramFiles(x86)...\",\r\n        \"Priority\": 1\r\n    },\r\n    \"Program3\" : \r\n    {\r\n        \"Filepath\": \"C:\\\\ProgramFiles(x86)...\",\r\n        \"Priority\": 3\r\n    }\r\n}}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

var threads = (JObject)obj["Threads"];

var sortedObj = new JObject(
    threads.Properties().OrderByDescending(p => (int)p.Value["Priority"])
);

Console.WriteLine(sortedObj.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: Worked! Also I think that "Threads" be an array but as json is the return from API can't modify this structure...